# Where is the admin bar instantiated?

Tags: footer, admin-bar

There are so many resources on how to enable, disable, change and fix the admin bar, but per a question from a student, we just want to follow the path to how it's made.

What we know:
1. The trail starts with footer.php -> wp_footer();
2. The trail ends with wp_includes/adminbar.php

What's the trail in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the backtrace of the adminbar rendering in the home page of the backend for WordPress 4.9.2

```
array (
  'file' => 'wp-admin/index.php',
  'line' => 100,
  'function' => 'include',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-admin/admin-header.php',
  'line' => 219,
  'function' => 'do_action',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/plugin.php',
  'line' => 457,
  'function' => 'do_action',
  'class' => 'WP_Hook',
  'type' => '->',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php',
  'line' => 310,
  'function' => 'apply_filters',
  'class' => 'WP_Hook',
  'type' => '->',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php',
  'line' => 286,
  'function' => 'wp_admin_bar_render',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/admin-bar.php',
  'line' => 92,
  'function' => 'render',
  'class' => 'WP_Admin_Bar',
  'type' => '->',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php',
  'line' => 263,
  'function' => '_render',
  'class' => 'WP_Admin_Bar',
  'type' => '->',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php',
  'line' => 413,
)
```

and here the path on the home page

```
array (
  'file' => 'index.php',
  'line' => 17,
  'function' => 'require',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-blog-header.php',
  'line' => 19,
  'function' => 'require_once',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/template-loader.php',
  'line' => 74,
  'function' => 'include',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-content/themes/storefront/page.php',
  'line' => 38,
  'function' => 'get_footer',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/general-template.php',
  'line' => 76,
  'function' => 'locate_template',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/template.php',
  'line' => 647,
  'function' => 'load_template',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/template.php',
  'line' => 688,
  'function' => 'require_once',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-content/themes/storefront/footer.php',
  'line' => 36,
  'function' => 'wp_footer',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/general-template.php',
  'line' => 2630,
  'function' => 'do_action',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/plugin.php',
  'line' => 457,
  'function' => 'do_action',
  'class' => 'WP_Hook',
  'type' => '->',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php',
  'line' => 310,
  'function' => 'apply_filters',
  'class' => 'WP_Hook',
  'type' => '->',
)
array (
  'file' => 'wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php',
  'line' => 286,
  'function' => 'wp_admin_bar_render',
)
```

Comment: How did you do that? And why doesn't the footer call show up?

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins `wp_footer` is front end only, this was from the Backend. The relevant action here is `in_admin_header` which is the second item in the backtrace (`wp-admin/admin-header.php:219`). Can't speak for how mmm did it, but you yould hook into the `admin_bar_init` action and then use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) to get the info.

Comment: @janh it's totally that, I use https://php.net/debug_backtrace to find such paths.

Comment: If I understand your comments correctly, I believe that my original question was not specific enough. What I didn't realize is that the admin bar may be called through a different path from the backend (Dashboard) than it is when it shows on the front end (Viewer side) when the viewer is logged in.

Comment: oh yes, I forget the frontend. I have edited my question to add the trace on the home page.

Comment: This has been a very informative discussion. In the end, the problem was caused by a badly done subdomain redirect. A setup I was not privy to. But, this information helped my student rule out possible causes to the problem. This answered my question, but my question was not about the actual problem!